# Nginx com api node

Tags: api, ubuntu, servidor, nginx

Eu estou com um problema a um tempo e não consigo resolver.
O problema é o seguinte:

Eu tenho um servidor que nele tem uma api rodando com PM2 na porta 3000.
Eu instalei o NGINX e estou tentando vincular a rota do meu dominio + path para realizar as requests para api. Eu gostaria de usar uma rota parecido com:

`www.dominio.com.br/api`

Porém não consigo configurar o NGINX para fazer isso.

Eu configurei o NGINX dessa forma:

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

E assim funciona, porém com a rota da seguinte maneira:

`www.dominio.com.br`

Eu tentei colocar o `/api` no complemento do location, desta forma:

`location /api {` 
OU
`location /api/ {` 
mas não funcionou..

Eu tentei tbm usar o upstream e não funcionou!
Configurei da seguinte maneira:

```
upstream teste_api {
   server http://localhost:3000;
}

location /api {
   set $upstream teste_api;
}
```

E quando rodei o comando: sudo nginx -t
É apresentado esse erro: `[emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:20`

Alguém me ajuda por favor?

Comment: Basicamente nas versões mais recentes vc precisaria fazer upstream normalmente no arquivo de configuração (ou a parte) e no seu arquivo de host (ou virtual) fazer o proxy_pass. Informe **qual versão do Nginx vc usa**?

Comment: nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)! Aparentemente o upstream não está sendo reconhecido no arquivo de configuração.

Comment: Vc poderia editar sua pergunta e adicionar o trecho de seu upstream. Informe tbm se vc recebe algum erro ao rodar o comando: **sudo nginx -t**

Comment: Pelo que vi é um erro de permissão! É isso mesmo?

Comment: Acredito que, vc precise remover a upstream diretiva para fora do bloco server. Ela esta dentro so seu block **server {}**? Esta diretiva (upstream) deve estar alocada no bloco **http{}**

Comment: Sim, esta dentro do bloco server! Vou fazer um teste colocando dentro do bloco http. O location fica dentro de http tbm?

Comment: Infelizmente tbm não funcionou, o erro agora foi: [emerg] "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1

Comment: o location/api deve ficar dentro do bloco server ... tente seguir o exemplo da resposta que adicionei e de um feedback do que esta resultando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente a diretiva **upstream** deve ser alocada no bloco `http {}` no arquivo de configuração do Nginx (nginx.conf) ... algo como isso:

**nginx.conf**

```
http {
    ##
    # node socket upstream
    ##
    upstream teste_api {
      ip_hash;
      server http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

Já no seu arquivo de configuração do host (se for único) ou de seus subdominios (virtual hosts) você deve definir a rota dentro do bloco `server {}` .... similar ao seguinte exemplo:

```
server {
    ##
    # socket
    ##
    location /api {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://teste_api;
    }
}
```

Note que no exemplo acima estou definindo os cabeçalhos de: upgrade, conexão, versão, "x-forwarded-for" e host ... você pode definir, omitir inúmeros cabeçalhos aqui mas, estes são os básicos.

No front-end basta chamar normalmente:

```
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://www.dominio.com.br/api')
```

---

**Fonte**:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream

Comment: Funcionou em partes! A configuração funcionou! Porém eu continuei com o mesmo erro! Se eu deixo apenas location /  - a request funciona normal, porém se eu acrescendo /api - a request não funciona, retorna o erro: {
    "message": "/api/users does not exist"
}

Comment: Eu tenho outros locations que funcionam quase bem tbm. Tenho locations de frontend que funciona por exemplo: location/admin/ - dai a rota fica www.dominio.com.br/admin/ - O único problema que tenho com isso, é que eu obrigatoriamente preciso colocar a ultima `/` no final da rota.. rsrs

Comment: Eu fiz os exemplos para **socket** mas, sim vc pode usar para requisições REST (get/post/del/put/...) a questão é tratá-las no seu Node

Comment: Entendi! Perfeito! Entendi 100%... Muito obrigado, foi de grande ajuda...